# mongodb: Is there any way of stoping mongod from trying to set a lock on mongod.lock?

Tags: mongodb

Because of the size of the mongodb database I'm trying to build and because I needed a filesystem that can handle parallel writes, I moved it on a cluster that has lustreFS, which fulfills these needs.

The problem is that I can't start mongod, so I can't connect anything to the database, because mongod can't get a lock on mongod.lock. I don't have root or sudo permissions but this does not seem to be the problem here because permissions are not mentioned, as you can see:

```
    [user@host mongo]$ ./mongod --dbpath=path-to-db
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=54974 port=27017 dbpath=path-to-db 64-bit host=hostname
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] 
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode is 1
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 0
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] **          http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt
2014-07-28T20:29:58.600+0300 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3
2014-07-28T20:29:58.601+0300 [initandlisten] git version: 255f67a66f9603c59380b2a389e386910bbb52cb
2014-07-28T20:29:58.601+0300 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build12.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-07-28T20:29:58.601+0300 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-07-28T20:29:58.601+0300 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "path-to-db" } }
2014-07-28T20:29:58.614+0300 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: path-to-db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-07-28T20:29:58.615+0300 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Could you please tell me if there's any way around that lock? And no, there weren't any other mongod instances running.

Solution: File locking was being disabled by cluster admins. After file locking was enabled, mongod started and accepted connections as it should.

Comment: Does the mongod.lock file exist?

Comment: It exists. I've also been told to delete it and whenever I do that, mongod creates it again the next time it's called. That's not an issue.

Comment: The file is required for operation of MongoDB - it should always be there when MongoDB is running. If it's there when MongoDB is not running it's an indication of a crash and you should look at the logs.

Comment: I checked the local copy of the database and this one too, has a mongod.lock (and it always ran perfectly). I don't think that's the issue. I think lustre, being an FS that allows parallel writing doesn't allow any program to hold a lock on a file. So the question remains. Can I avoid that lock?

Comment: MongoDB will create the lock file when it starts and delete it when it shutsdown, you can't prevent that. If the file exists when you are starting up MongoDB then there is another problem - the file should not already exist. It should only exist while MongoDB is running.

Comment: Ok.. I'll pick another project then. Thanks. In the meantime, this question remains open.